# insert multiple records with one ID in single query

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Hello i want insert data into 2 different tables.

```
First table 'Events:'

id,
name,
desc,
date

Second table 'Events_sub_cat:'

id,
event_id,
name,
desc,
date
```

I want to insert 2 different data in one query like:

```
INSERT INTO Events (name, desc, date) VALUES ('name', 'desc', 'date')
INSERT INTO Events_sub_cat (event_id, name, desc, date) VALUES (event_id, 'name', 'desc', 'date')
```

And i want get in the same query the ID of the even what i just inserted in table 'Events'
to let know to another INSERT what is the 'event_id'

Comment: I think you're looking for `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

There you go a suggestion:

[Insert records into two table at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315976/insert-records-into-two-table-at-once/19318415#19318415)

As said in the post, there's no way to insert without using mysql_insert_id()

Answer (score 0):

functions such as  lmysql_insert_id() return the last inserted id.

Answer (score 0):

you can select the last id from Events and put it in the second insert