# Insert into multiple tables at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert data into multiple tables but I can't get it to work.

There is a projects table and a tag table. When I creat a new project I want the project data to go into the project table and the tags that I post in the same form to go into the tag table. I have no idea how to do this.

Also, the tag table uses the project_id from the project table. The id is set with auto increment. How can I use the id from the project table in the tag table when they are created at the same time?

This is the query I use to insert into the projects table:

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO projects (project_title, project_summary, project_content, project_timestamp, photo_name, photo) VALUES('$title','$summary','$content','$time','$image_name','project_pics/$image_name')");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315976/insert-records-into-two-table-at-once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$q1=mysql_query("insert into tab1");
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$q2=mysql_query("insert into tab2 (id) values ('$id')")
```

Comment: Thanks! Inserting into both tables works now. However the mysql_insert_id() doesn't work because I use mysqli. Is there something like that for mysqli?

Comment: $id=$mysqli->insert_id;

Comment: I now have this:

$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO projects (project_title, project_summary, project_content, project_timestamp, photo_name, photo) VALUES('$title','$summary','$content','$time','$image_name','project_pics/$image_name')");
            $id = $mysqli->insert_id;
            $query2 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tags (project_id, tag) values ('$id', '$tag')");


And i get an Undefined variable mysqli notice and Trying to get property of non-object notice

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 2nd table storing id or not

Comment: check for 2nd table id column u given auto increment if yes remove it and try

Comment: project_id column doesn't have auto increment. I really don't know what's wrong. Phpstorm says that $mysqli is an undefined variable.

Answer (score 1):

you can insert it by using two different queries 
for example-

```
$query1=my_query("insert into table1");
$id = insert_id();
$query2=my_query("insert into table2 (id) values ('$id')")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using mysqli to [get the last inserted id](https://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id)

```
$mysqli->query($query);  
printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd run your first query on table1, then get the insert id of the previous row and insert in table2

https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id

hope this helps

---

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you put both queries in one transaction